# Wordpress Customizer shows Style in wp_head()

Tags: wordpress

This is a chunk of my code:

Up here I got Sections, Settings and Controls

```
function my_theme_css_customizer() {

?>
<style type="text/css">

header {background-color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('header-background-color')?>;}

</style>
```

Down here the actions....

Anyways, the thing is that this will input the style inside the WP_head() and if you check the console you can see the different stylesheets and at the end you can also see this style.

```
<style type="text/css">

header {background-color:#ffffff;}

</style>
```

Is it possible to prevent this from happening? Basically I don`t want WP_HEAD() displaying that style because my theme customizer is kinda big.

Any help will be really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.
Greetings.

Comment: "input the style inside the WP_head()" What does this mean (input...inside)?

Comment: Hi Nabil, I deleted my last answer since it made no sense. My issue is that when I check my theme in Chrome and check the console, the console shows the different styles path im using, same with the JS scripts, and then it shows the style used in the customizer. What I want it to do is to show that like a file or not show it at all.. Thanks again!

Comment: [Console Image](http://i1095.photobucket.com/albums/i468/chickenjoe2005/wphead.jpg)